# Can one become so sensitive by an enlightenment that one can't have people near/around you?

Tags: personal-practice

Is this good or 'bad' and should there be something done about it? So some person just picks up to much 'information' about other humans that it makes oneself emotionally to much loaded.
Especially during nights with out of the body experiences.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is certainly possible to be *spiritually* hyper-sensitive however this is more related to expanded states of consciousness rather than Buddhist enlightenment. In Buddhist enlightenment, all things, both internally & externally are viewed as not-self (*anatta*) and with dispassion (*viraga*) & equanimity (*upekkha*). Some spiritually/consciously expanded people live their lives is solitude however this does not mean they are enlightened in a Buddhist sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "enlightenment" you mean some profound realization, but not Nirvana. In this case the answer to your question is "yes".

If this sensitivity is troubling you, then it's bad and you should do something about it. If it's not troubling you, it's neither good nor bad and you don't need to do anything about it. If it's making your life easier, then it's good and you don't need to do anything about it.

On the other hand, speaking about "enlightenment" as Nirvana:

If one before Nirvana is sensitive to people because of views about self, after Nirvana not sensitive to people.

If one before Nirvana is sensitive to people not because of views about self, after Nirvana still sensitive to people.

If one before Nirvana is not sensitive to people because of views about self, after Nirvana not sensitive to people.

If one before Nirvana is not sensitive to people not because of views about self, after Nirvana not sensitive to people.